# Check if "comment" is the first one, then do not delete it

Tags: laravel

I am totally new to Laravel.
So I have a little question. I have an app where you can create a ticket. The ticket body is saved in the table comments. All additional comments are also saved in this table.
So, when the user tried to delete a comment I will check if this is the first comment (so the ticket body) and don't allow this, but it is not working. The comment can still be deleted:

```
public function deleteComment($id) {
    if(Comment::where('id', $id)->exists()) {

        $ticket_id = Comment::where('id', $id)->pluck('ticket_id');
        $first_id = Comment::where('ticket_id', $ticket_id)->get('id')->first();
        if($first_id == $id){
            return response()->json([
                "message" => "Cloud not delete comment, because it is the first comment"
            ], 405);
        }
        else{
            $comment = Comment::find($id);
            $comment->delete();

            return response()->json([
                "message" => "Comment deleted"
            ], 202);
        }
    } else {
        return response()->json([
            "message" => "Comment not found"
        ], 404);
    }
}
```

Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Try this

```
public function deleteComment($id) {
    if(Comment::where('id', $id)->exists()) {

        $ticket_id = Comment::where('id', $id)->first();
        $first_id = Comment::where('ticket_id', $ticket_id->ticket_id)->first();
        if($first_id->id == $id){
            return response()->json([
                "message" => "Cloud not delete comment, because it is the first comment"
            ], 405);
        }
        else{
            $comment = Comment::find($id);
            $comment->delete();

            return response()->json([
                "message" => "Comment deleted"
            ], 202);
        }
    } else {
        return response()->json([
            "message" => "Comment not found"
        ], 404);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$comment = Comment::where('id', $id)->get();
if(count($comment) > 1){
    $comment = Comment::find($id);
    $comment->delete();
}else...
```

Check for collection differences,not tested

```
$comment = Comment::where('id', $id)->get();
$commentFirst = Comment::where('id', $id)->first();
$diff = $comment->diff($commentFirst);
if(count($diff->all()) > 0){
    $comment = Comment::find($id);
    $comment->delete();
}else...
```

Comment: The problem is that I have an API too. When a user is typing the wrong id it still can be deleted so, I must check if it is the first entry.